# Need Unique Username for login in swift (Firebase)

Tags: swift

I mustn't use firebase auth. How can I make the username unique? I tried many different way but, I did not get any results. I use realtime database

```
let firestoreDB = Firestore.firestore()

        let firestoreReference : DocumentReference?

        let firestoreUser = ["adsoyad" : adSoyadText.text! , "username" : kullanciAdiText.text! , "password" : sifreText.text! , "adres" : adresText.text! , "status" : 0 , "kazanılanpara" : 0 , "cekilenpara" : 0] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Is the username created by the user? and do you require a user friendly username?

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: Username created by the user. I take username by register screen. But, username can be retrieved over and over because it is not unique. I think only way is create auth and write again different collection with other information in Firebase RealTime Database.